# Clojure: Rename and select keys from map with one iteration

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I want to both rename-keys and select-keys from a map.
The simple way of doing is with:

```
(-> m
    (rename-keys new-names)
    (select-keys (vals new-names)))
```

But this will itetate over the entire map twice.
Is there a way to do it with one iteration?

Comment: if your new-names is quite small but m is large, you could just select first over `(**keys** new-names)` and then rename the (small) result

Comment: If you don't need the result to be a map but just a function you can also do it with no iteration: `(comp m new-names-to-old-names-map)`

Comment: Why wouldn't you do somethnig like this? `{:new-key-1 (my-map :old-key-1) :new-key-2 (my-map :old-key-2) :new-key-3 (my-map :old-key-3)}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, there is a way to do it with a single iteration.

You could do it using [`reduce-kv` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv):

```clj
(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %3 (get m %2)) {} new-names)
```

or just a for loop:

```clj
(into {} (for [[k v] new-names] [v (get m k)]))
```

If you want a really simple piece of code, you could use [`fmap` function](http://clojure.github.io/algo.generic/clojure.algo.generic.functor-api.html#clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap) from [`algo.generic` library](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic):

```clj
(fmap m (map-invert new-names))
```